# Email alert issue. Email is sent every time the opportunity is updated

Tags: email-alert

I added a checkbox in the opportunity object so that an email is sent to a group of people whenever the opportunity is approved. Only issue is that an email is sent every time the opportunity is updated. Is there a way to limit it to only one notification or something? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the workflow rule criteria you should verify if previous value is NOT approved and current value is approved, then only, you should send an email.

Comment: Yeah, I just noticed that I had picked the wrong option. I changed to "Evaluate the rule when a record is created, and any time it's edited to subsequently meet criteria". Seems to be working now. Did I get it right? :)

Comment: but also, put the condition to make it full proof

Comment: I have the following rule criteria:
Field: Opportunity: Opportunity Approved
Operator: Equals
Value: True

Comment: Is that what you meant?

Comment: no, also check, previous value is not true and current value is true, otherwise it will always send the email

Comment: hmmm... but there are only 3 options.

Comment: created /
created, and every time it's edited /
created, and any time it's edited to subsequently meet criteria

Comment: put `ISCHANGED(Approved) && Opportunity Approved = true)` as formula and `Evaluate the rule when a record is: `created, and every time it's edited`